# Cordova run does not build plugin classes

Tags: java, android, cordova, ant, inappbrowser

I am getting crazy here: it has been 3 hours that I try to understand why InAppBrowser does not work. I have removed the platforms/android folder completely, added again the plugin via the CLI only to see in `adb logcat` that the `InAppBrowser` plugin is not found. Indeed, I do not see the classes generated in the platforms/android/ant/build. On the computer of my colleague, everything is fine, the classes are generated and the plugin works. We have basically the same setup and I do not see why those classes are not generated. I am not an expert in Ant builds.

Can someone point me to the right direction ?

[EDIT] More information:

To install the plugin, I did as suggested in https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/doc/index.md:
`cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser`

I did run `cordova build`.

Comment: how are you adding the plugin? and did you run `cordova build` after adding the plugin?

Comment: Thanks for helping :) I edited the post for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your /plugins/android.json got somehow corrupted.

The simpliest I could recommend you is to remove the /plugins folder and re-add all the plugins you need in your project.